# How to maintain cache in ClickHouse?

Tags: caching, memory, clickhouse

I use crontab to schedule a SQL that queries a big table every 2 hours.

```
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,many_cols from big_table format Null
```

It takes anywhere from 5 minutes to 30 seconds at a time.

What I can see from the `query_log` is that when the SQL time is low, the `MarkCacheHits` value is high, when the time is high, the `MarkCacheHits` value is low, and the `MarkCacheMiss` value is high.

- And I'm wondering how to make mark cache hit as many as possible? (This is probably not the only big table that needs to be warmed up)
- Will mark cache be replaced by other queries and what is its limit?
- Does the warm-up way of selecting specific columns really work for an aggregate query of those columns? For example, warm-up SQL is as above, and the aggregate query can be `select a,sum(if(b,c,0)) from big_table group by a`
- My clickhouse server has been hanging occasionally recently, and I can't see any errors or exceptions at the corresponding time from the log. Could this be related to my regular warm-up query of the big table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality you placing data into Linux disk cache.

> Will mark cache be replaced by other queries and what is its limit?

yes, will be replaced, 5GB `<mark_cache_size>5368709120</mark_cache_size>`

> Does the warm-up way of selecting specific columns really work for an aggregate query of those columns?

Yes because you put files into Linux cache.

> Could this be related to my regular warm-up query of the big table?

No.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can highly concurrent queries (dozens) cause deadlocks?

Comment: It should not. Open a new issue https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues with a full description and steps to reproduce